# Simulate C# Lambda methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to simulate the C# [Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) method, which can be used to determine whether if a collection has any matching objects based on a lambda expression.

I used jQuery's [$.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to make things easier:

```
Array.prototype.any = function (expr) {

    if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined')
        throw new ReferenceError('jQuery not loaded');

    return $.grep(this, function (x, i) {
        return eval(expr);
    }).length > 0;

};

var foo = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a:1, b: 3 }];

console.log(foo.any('x.a === 1')); //true
console.log(foo.any('x.a === 2')); //false
```

I know that `eval()` is bad practice for obvious reasons. But is it ok in this case, since I won't use this with anything related to some user inputs?

Can this be done without `eval()`? I can't figure out a way to pass an expression to the function without evaluating it.

http://jsfiddle.net/dgGvN/

Comment: Can't you pass a function instead of an expression string? That would be more js-friendly.

Comment: @bfavaretto: I think your comment makes a good answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh I was too slow, now it would be pointless given the current answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you take a good look at JS closures. In particular, what you did there can be done natively in JS by using the [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
[{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a:1, b: 3 }].some(function(x) { return x.a === 1; }); // true
[{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a:1, b: 3 }].some(function(x) { return x.a === 2; }); // false
```

edit: in this case we're not really using closures but rather plain simple anonymous functions...

Comment: Thanks. They should have called it Any() ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Pass in a function:

```
Array.prototype.any = function (expr) {

    if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined')
        throw new ReferenceError('jQuery not loaded');

    return $.grep(this, expr).length > 0;

};

var foo = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a:1, b: 3 }];

console.log(foo.any(function(x, i){return x.a === 1})); //true
console.log(foo.any(function(x, i){return x.a === 2})); //false
```

Comment: Thanks. This way it'll work just like the some() method that @CAFxX mentioned (which I obviously didn't know about)